# get datetimepicker value after 30 day

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have program that record users payment , user get cellphone credit available for 30 day , what i need to do is when pick 1-1-2015 in datetimepiker i want to get 30 day after this day so the value will be 1-2-2015 .
how can i do this ??

```
      Dim Day = DateTimePicker1.Value.Day
    Dim Month = DateTimePicker1.Value.Month
    Dim Year = DateTimePicker1.Value.Year

    Dim d As Integer = Day + 30
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim dd As Integer
    Dim mm As Integer

    If d > 30 Then
        dd = d - 30
        m = Month + 1
    End If
    If m > 12 Then
        mm = Month - 12
        Year = Year + 1

        TextBox1.Text = dd & "-" & mm & "-" & Year
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = dd & "-" & m & "-" & Year
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating with `Integers` you should use  `DateTime.AddDays`:

```
Dim dt As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim thirtyDaysAfter As Date = dt.AddDays(30)
TextBox1.Text = thirtyDaysAfter.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

If you instead want the next month you can use `dt.AddMonths(1)`.